# How to create custom inline rows with Eureka?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I would like implement a custom `inline` `cell` with Eureka like described 
[here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#how-to-create-custom-inline-rows). But I have some problems to make in compile in my concrete case. Swift compiler crashes when I try to run with the following error.

```
...
Call parameter type does not match function signature!
...
1.  Running pass 'Module Verifier' on function'@_TWaC7TonyPro22ServiceCheckInlineRow26Eureka13InlineRowTypeS_'
...
```

My collapsable Row and Cell.

```
public final class ServiceRow: Row<Service, ServiceCell>, RowType {
...
}

public class ServiceCell: Cell<Service>, CellType {
...
}
```

My inline row

```
public class ServiceCheckInlineRow: ImageCheckInlineRow<Service>, InlineRowType {
    public typealias InlineRow = ServiceRow

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        onExpandInlineRow { cell, row, _ in
            let color = cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor
            row.onCollapseInlineRow { cell, _, _ in
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = color
            }
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = cell.tintColor
        }
    }

    public override func customDidSelect() {
        super.customDidSelect()
        if !isDisabled {
            toggleInlineRow()
        }
    }

    public func setupInlineRow(inlineRow: InlineRow) {

    }
}

public class ImageCheckInlineRow<T where T: Equatable, T: ServiceType>: Row<T, ImageCheckCell<T>>, SelectableRowType, RowType {
    public var selectableValue: T?
    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        displayValueFor = nil
    }
}
```

I assume that the origin of the problem is the `aliasType InlineRow` but I do not find why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello I had been working on your question and this are my results, this is how looks

[image]

I will post two examples of custom inline rows with eureka

First example is a custom inline row with slider with values from 0..100

```
public class ServiceInlineCell<T: Equatable> : Cell<T>, CellType {

    required public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    public override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        accessoryType = .None
        editingAccessoryType =  .None
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()
        selectionStyle = row.isDisabled ? .None : .Default
    }

    public override func didSelect() {
        super.didSelect()
        row.deselect()
    }
}

//MARK: PickerInlineRow

public class _ServiceInlineRow : Row<Float, ServiceInlineCell<Float>>, NoValueDisplayTextConformance {

    public typealias InlineRow = SliderRow
    public var options = [Float]()
    public var noValueDisplayText: String?

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
    }
}

/// A generic inline row where the user can pick an option from a picker view
public final class ServiceInlineRow<T where T: Equatable> : _ServiceInlineRow, RowType, InlineRowType {

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        onExpandInlineRow { cell, row, _ in
            let color = cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor
            row.onCollapseInlineRow { cell, _, _ in
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = color
            }
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = cell.tintColor
        }
    }

    public override func customDidSelect() {
        super.customDidSelect()
        if !isDisabled {
            toggleInlineRow()
        }
    }

    public func setupInlineRow(inlineRow: InlineRow) {
        inlineRow.maximumValue = 100
        inlineRow.steps = UInt(inlineRow.maximumValue / 10)
        inlineRow.displayValueFor = {(Float) in
            return "\(Float)"
        }
    }


}
```

and then on your form you need to put this

```
    <<< ServiceInlineRow<Float>("PickerInlineRow") { (row : ServiceInlineRow<Float>) -> Void in
        row.title = row.tag
        row.value = 0
    }
```

And this is another example with an slider but with string values

```
public class CustomSliderInlineCell<T: Equatable> : Cell<T>, CellType {

    required public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    public override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        accessoryType = .None
        editingAccessoryType =  .None
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()
        selectionStyle = row.isDisabled ? .None : .Default
    }

    public override func didSelect() {
        super.didSelect()
        row.deselect()
    }
}

//MARK: PickerInlineRow

public class _CustomSliderInlineRow<T where T: Equatable> : Row<T, CustomSliderInlineCell<T>>, NoValueDisplayTextConformance {

    public typealias InlineRow = CustomSliderRow<T>
    public var options = [T]()
    public var noValueDisplayText: String?

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
    }
}

/// A generic inline row where the user can pick an option from a picker view
public final class CustomSliderInlineRow<T where T: Equatable> : _CustomSliderInlineRow<T>, RowType, InlineRowType {

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        onExpandInlineRow { cell, row, _ in
            let color = cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor
            row.onCollapseInlineRow { cell, _, _ in
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = color
            }
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = cell.tintColor
        }
    }

    public override func customDidSelect() {
        super.customDidSelect()
        if !isDisabled {
            toggleInlineRow()
        }
    }

    public func setupInlineRow(inlineRow: InlineRow) {
        inlineRow.values = options
        inlineRow.displayValueFor = self.displayValueFor
    }
}
```

And the definition for CustomSliderRow and Cell

```
public class CustomSliderCell<T: Equatable>: Cell<T>, CellType {

    public required init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    public var titleLabel: UILabel! {
        textLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textLabel?.setContentHuggingPriority(500, forAxis: .Horizontal)
        return textLabel
    }
    public var valueLabel: UILabel! {
        detailTextLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        detailTextLabel?.setContentHuggingPriority(500, forAxis: .Horizontal)
        return detailTextLabel
    }
    lazy public var slider: UISlider = {
        let result = UISlider()
        result.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        result.setContentHuggingPriority(500, forAxis: .Horizontal)
        return result
    }()
    public var formatter: NSNumberFormatter?

    public override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        selectionStyle = .None
        slider.minimumValue = sliderRow.minimumValue
        slider.maximumValue = sliderRow.maximumValue
        print(sliderRow.values.count)
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomSliderCell.valueChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

        if shouldShowTitle() {
            contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
            contentView.addSubview(valueLabel!)
        }
        contentView.addSubview(slider)

        let views = ["titleLabel" : titleLabel, "valueLabel" : valueLabel, "slider" : slider]
        let metrics = ["hPadding" : 16.0, "vPadding" : 12.0, "spacing" : 12.0]

        if shouldShowTitle() {
            contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-hPadding-[titleLabel]-[valueLabel]-hPadding-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllBaseline, metrics: metrics, views: views))
            contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-vPadding-[titleLabel]-spacing-[slider]-vPadding-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeft, metrics: metrics, views: views))

        } else {
            contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-vPadding-[slider]-vPadding-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeft, metrics: metrics, views: views))
        }
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-hPadding-[slider]-hPadding-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllBaseline, metrics: metrics, views: views))
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()
        if !shouldShowTitle() {
            textLabel?.text = nil
            detailTextLabel?.text = nil
        }
        //slider.value = row.value ?? 0.0
        slider.value = 0.0
    }

    func valueChanged() {
        let roundedValue: Float
        //let steps = Float(sliderRow.steps)
        let steps = Float(sliderRow.values.count-1)
        if steps > 0 {
            let stepValue = round((slider.value - slider.minimumValue) / (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue) * steps)
            let stepAmount = (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue) / steps
            roundedValue = stepValue * stepAmount + self.slider.minimumValue
        }
        else {
            roundedValue = slider.value
        }
        //row.value = roundedValue
        row.value = sliderRow.values[Int(roundedValue)]
        if shouldShowTitle() {
            valueLabel.text = "\(row.value!)"
        }
    }

    private func shouldShowTitle() -> Bool {
        return row.title?.isEmpty == false
    }

    private var sliderRow: CustomSliderRow<T> {
        return row as! CustomSliderRow
    }
}

/// A row that displays a UISlider. If there is a title set then the title and value will appear above the UISlider.
public final class CustomSliderRow<T: Equatable>: Row<T, CustomSliderCell<T>>, RowType {

    public var minimumValue: Float = 0.0
    public var maximumValue: Float = 10.0
    public var steps: UInt = 20
    public var values : [T] = [T](){
        willSet(newValues)
        {
          maximumValue = Float(newValues.count-1)
          steps = UInt(newValues.count)
          cell.setup()
        }
    }

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
    }


}
```

And in your form you need to put

```
<<< CustomSliderInlineRow<String>("CustomSliderRow"){ (row : CustomSliderInlineRow<String>) -> Void in
                row.title = row.tag
                row.options = ["Value1","Value2","Value3"]
                row.value = "Value1"
        }
```

I hope this helps you, regards