# Dynamic TextRow in Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am trying to do a SegmentedRow. And in each section, there are TextRows. These TextRows are dynamic in number. I tried:

```
 +++ Section()
            <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
                $0.options = ["Assets", "Notes", "Photos"]
                $0.value = "Assets"
            }
            +++ Section(){
                $0.tag = "assets_s"
                $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Assets'" // .Predicate(NSPredicate(format: "$segments != 'Sport'"))
            }
            for t in myarray{
                <<< TextRow(){
                $0.title = "Which is your favourite soccer player?"
            }

            }
```

I tried putting the for loop there but I get an error in the succeeding lines.

Comment: Can you post what is myarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that what you need is something like this, and this is how it looks

[image]

```
class ViewController2: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let assets = [String](arrayLiteral: "asset1","asset2","asset3")
        let notes = [String](arrayLiteral: "note1","note2","note3")
        let photos = [String](arrayLiteral: "photo1","photo2","photo3")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        form  +++ Section()
            <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
                $0.options = ["Assets", "Notes", "Photos"]
                $0.value = "Assets"
                }.onChange({ (segmented) in
                    if(segmented.value == "Assets")
                    {
                        segmented.section!.removeLast(segmented.section!.count - 1)

                        for value in assets
                        {
                            segmented.section! <<< TextRow(){
                                $0.title = value
                            }
                        }
                    }
                     if(segmented.value == "Notes")
                    {
                        segmented.section!.removeLast(segmented.section!.count - 1)

                        for value in notes
                        {
                            segmented.section! <<< ButtonRow(){
                                $0.title = value
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(segmented.value == "Photos")
                    {
                        segmented.section!.removeLast(segmented.section!.count - 1)

                        for value in photos
                        {
                            segmented.section! <<< TextRow(){
                                $0.title = value
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

    }

}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: I wonder if you have tried creating custom rows? Like a row that has an UIImage view in it?

Comment: check this maybe helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767816/how-to-create-custom-inline-rows-with-eureka/37998235#37998235

Comment: I created a question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188514/custom-row-in-eureka