# Custom Row in Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am trying to create a custom row that shows an image. So I started by trying the basic custom row indicated in Eureka's page: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#basic-custom-rows

Here's the code I am using:

```
import Eureka

    public class CustomCell2: Cell<Bool>, CellType{
        @IBOutlet weak var switchControl: UISwitch!
        @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

        public override func setup() {
            super.setup()
            switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomCell2.switchValueChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        }

        func switchValueChanged(){
            row.value = switchControl.on
            row.updateCell() // Re-draws the cell which calls 'update' bellow
        }

        public override func update() {
            super.update()
            backgroundColor = (row.value ?? false) ? .whiteColor() : .blackColor()
        }
    }
    public final class CustomRow: Row<Bool, CustomCell2>, RowType {
        required public init(tag: String?) {
            super.init(tag: tag)
            // We set the cellProvider to load the .xib corresponding to our cell
            cellProvider = CellProvider<CustomCell2>(nibName: "CustomCell2")
        }
    }
```

And that is saved as CustomCell2.swift. I am calling that custom row using this: `futurSection <<< CustomRow ("")`

But I am getting an error: `Could not load NIB in bundle with name 'CustomCell2'`

And, how do I change that into an UIImage?

Comment: You have CustomCell2 nib defined?

Comment: I guess I don't have that. I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: ok, I will check and post any result, regards

Comment: Hey @JaysonTamayo, I hope you fixed your problem, in case you not, this may be helpful https://blog.xmartlabs.com/2016/09/06/Eureka-custom-row-tutorial/

Answer (score 6):

Hello I had been reviewing your question and this are my results

I use your code and make some modifications this is my `EurekaCustomImageCell.swift`

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

public class CustomCell2: Cell<Bool>, CellType{


    @IBOutlet weak var customImage: UIImageView!
    public override func setup() {
        super.setup()
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()
        backgroundColor = (row.value ?? false) ? .whiteColor() : .blackColor()
    }
}
public final class CustomRow: Row<Bool, CustomCell2>, RowType {
    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        // We set the cellProvider to load the .xib corresponding to our cell
        cellProvider = CellProvider<CustomCell2>(nibName: "CustomCell2")
    }
}
```

as you can see here is a `@IBOutlet weak var customImage: UIImageView!` this is an outlet defined in my xib file for this custom cell, check this image

[image]

I hope this helps you, this works for me without problems