# Swift Eureka - custom row "cannot convert to expected argument type BaseRow"

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

As many others, i want to implement a custom row in Eureka.

So i followed the tutorial and even had a look into some of the examples provided by the Eureka-Community.

This is my code:

```
open class EditorTextCell: Cell<Field>, CellType {
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var questionField: UITextField!
// TODO 
}
```

The row is:

```
public final class EditorTextRow: Row<EditorTextCell>, RowType {
    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        cellProvider = CellProvider<EditorTextCell>(nibName: "EditorTextCell")
    }
}
```

And my data structure is as simple as:

```
public class Field: Object {
    dynamic var question = ""
    dynamic var mandatory = false
}
```

As far as i understand, i need a data structure that holds the data my custom row will be holding / generating after user interaction. This custom data structure is a Realm object in my case, so i figured - why not reuse it? After that the custom data structure should be passed into the `Cell<MyDataStructure>` of my custom cell i am defining. The custom row is merely loading my nib and declaring what cell to use that for with `Row<MyCustomCell>`. Thats all. Correct?

I am getting the error "Cannot convert value of type UITableViewCell to expected argument type BaseRow" on the line where i try to instantiate my custom row like `form.last! <<< EditorTextCell()`.

I read the official documentation, where it says:
`Custom rows need to subclass Row<CellType> and conform to RowType protocol. Custom cells need to subclass Cell<ValueType> and conform to CellType protocol.` - which is what i am doing. I also found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188514/custom-row-in-eureka) on stackoverflow, which gives some advice i am already following. And i had a look at [this](https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/CreditCardRow/tree/master/Sources), which is an official example. I basically just wrote down what they did and yet it doesn't work.

Why?

The only difference i see is that they write a separate underscore type for `Row<MyCustomCell>` and do some stuff i don't understand there. I don't see why that's necessary, if the offical documentation on their github says it enough to subclass and adopt `Row<MyCustomCell>` and `RowType`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is that you have to replace `EditorTextCell` with `EditorTextRow` in your code:

```
form.last! <<< EditorTextRow()
```