# Eureka activity indicator row

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I have a `Swift 3.0` application using `Eureka Forms`.

I would like to have an `activity indicator` row but I think you need to create a custom row for this.

> Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can create custom rows with Eureka. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Can you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188514/custom-row-in-eureka?