# Eureka rangeSliderRow

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

Is there any way to create range slider with eureka?

Something like this.

```
<<< RangeSlideRow() {
                        $0.maxValue = 10000
                        $0.minValue = 0
                        $0.selectedMaxValue = 9000
                        $0.selectedMinValue = 5
                    }
```

Comment: You can check this maybe helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767816/how-to-create-custom-inline-rows-with-eureka/37998235#37998235

Comment: works for you @korgx9?

Comment: Sorry still didn't check... I'll let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no range slider in eureka because the UISlider does not support it. You will have to create your own RangeSlideRow based on some existing rangeslider implementations.

Check the SliderRow implementation in Eureka for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I know I came late to the party but maybe next time [this will be useful](https://blog.xmartlabs.com/2016/09/06/Eureka-custom-row-tutorial/).

I encourage you to share your row in the [Eureka Community](https://github.com/EurekaCommunity) if you think is going to be helpful to anyone :) Thanks!

Comment: I've mixed other library (RangeSlider) with Eureka. If it is normal way for Eureka then i can share it.

Comment: That's the idea for the Eureka Community, we want to have all the custom rows there to avoid having a project hard to understand or maintain and keep the dependencies of its rows apart for the core.

Comment: Enrique Galindo  check my answer, this is how I did tit

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it

[swift 3 version](https://github.com/korgx9/RangeSlider-Swift)

First Installed [TTRangeSlider](https://github.com/TomThorpe/TTRangeSlider)

Then created RangeViewCell.xib file with outlets

Then created file RangeViewCell.swift

Connected Outlets

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Eureka
import TTRangeSlider

public class RangeViewCell: Cell<String>, CellType, TTRangeSliderDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var rangeSlider: TTRangeSlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fromLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var toLabel: UILabel!

    private var umt = ""
    required public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    public override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        rangeSlider.delegate = self
        accessoryType = .None
        editingAccessoryType =  .None
        textLabel?.text = nil
        detailTextLabel?.text = nil

        titleLabel.text = row.title

        rangeSlider.minValue        = rangeViewRow.minValue
        rangeSlider.maxValue        = rangeViewRow.maxValue

        if let selectedMin = rangeViewRow.selectedMinimumValue {
            rangeSlider.selectedMinimum = selectedMin
        }

        if let selectedMax = rangeViewRow.selectedMaximumValue {
            rangeSlider.selectedMaximum = selectedMax
        }

        if let step = rangeViewRow.step {
            rangeSlider.step = step
        }

        umt = ""
        if let umtC = rangeViewRow.unitMeassureText {
            umt = umtC
        }

        rangeSlider.enableStep = true
        updateLabelsValues(rangeSlider.selectedMinimum, max: rangeSlider.selectedMaximum)
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()
        accessoryType = .None
        editingAccessoryType =  .None
        textLabel?.text = nil
        detailTextLabel?.text = nil
    }

    public override func didSelect() {

    }

    public func rangeSlider(sender: TTRangeSlider!, didChangeSelectedMinimumValue selectedMinimum: Float, andMaximumValue selectedMaximum: Float) {
        updateLabelsValues(selectedMinimum, max: selectedMaximum)
    }

    private var rangeViewRow: RangeViewRow {
        return row as! RangeViewRow
    }

    func updateLabelsValues(min:Float, max: Float) {

        if min == rangeSlider.minValue && max == rangeSlider.maxValue {
            fromLabel.hidden    = false
            toLabel.hidden      = true
            fromLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("All", comment: "Eureka range slider label if all selected")
        }
        else if min == rangeSlider.minValue && max != rangeSlider.maxValue {
            fromLabel.hidden    = true
            toLabel.hidden      = false

            toLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("to", comment: "Eureka range slider label to") + " " + max.description + " " + umt
        }
        else if min != rangeSlider.minValue && max == rangeSlider.maxValue {
            fromLabel.hidden    = false
            toLabel.hidden      = true

            fromLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("from", comment: "Eureka range slider label from") + " " + min.description + " " + umt
        }
        else {
            fromLabel.hidden    = false
            toLabel.hidden      = false
            fromLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("from", comment: "Eureka range slider label from") + " " + min.description + " " + umt
            toLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("to", comment: "Eureka range slider label to") + " " + max.description + " " + umt
        }

        row.value = "\(min):\(max)"
    }
}

public final class RangeViewRow: Row<String, RangeViewCell>, RowType {
    public var minValue: Float = 0.0
    public var maxValue: Float = 1.0
    public var selectedMinimumValue: Float?
    public var selectedMaximumValue: Float?
    public var unitMeassureText: String?
    public var step: Float?


    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        cellProvider = CellProvider<RangeViewCell>(nibName: "RangeViewCell")
    }
}
```

And here how to use it

```
<<< RangeViewRow("square") {
                $0.title = NSLocalizedString("Square", comment: "Appartment square")
                $0.minValue = 0
                $0.maxValue = 1000
                $0.selectedMinimumValue = 0
                $0.selectedMaximumValue = 1000
                $0.step = 10
                $0.unitMeassureText = "m²"
                }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) -> () in
                    cell.rangeSlider.handleColor = Constants.Color.primaryColor
                    cell.rangeSlider.lineHeight = 3.0
                    cell.rangeSlider.tintColor = Constants.Color.primaryColor
                    cell.fromLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
                    cell.toLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
                })
```