# Eureka - Custom Inline Row

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am trying to write a custom inline row using `Eureka` but I couldn't do it by following the documentation in the `Github` page of the library.

Also I copy-pasted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767816/how-to-create-custom-inline-rows-with-eureka) but it throws a `segmentation error`. I also tried searching for tutorials on the internet to follow but there is none.

Can someone clearly and basically explain how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See if [this is the place](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/d803646c2eec7d874c982ccf11155bb89530f3f8/Example/Example/ViewController.swift#L86) you want to look into

Also, are you using this library just to do a collapsible cell? You can do that by yourself and that is really not hard & a lot of code to implement. Check out [this exmaple](https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/). All you need is to define child cells and parent cells in a section and reload it with animation!

I know it's a long tutorial. You can probably skip the top half, and start reading from ***Expanding and Collapsing*** section. The basic idea is, a collapsible cell and the collapsed cell are within a section, and you have a variable per section of cells to remember if the section is expanded or not. When clicked on the first cell of the section, if it's already expanded, reduce the cell count to one and do a reload to this section using animation `Fade`. and vice versa. This Fade animation will produce the animation you want.

Comment: hey, thank you for your response. Actually I am heavily using `Eureka` in the project. I saw your first link already and I also did not help. If you have further knowledge about this, can you explain how to write a custom inline row from scratch please?

Comment: @Faruk Updated the answer but you should really look at the tutorial. You will learn a lot.

Comment: yep you are correct sir :) I need to learn reading tutorials properly. I am aware of that this is a great library but `Generic`s confuses my mind.